# Go Golang net.Dial Send 1 request but read the second response

Tags: go

I am using Go to read a reply from a sever using net.Dial. The code below works but the server sends back 2 replys. To read the second reply I would have to read the reply again. Is there an easier way to discard the first reply and grab the second reply? Regards

```
_, err = conn.Write([]byte(login))
reply := make([]byte, 5000)

_, err = conn.Read(reply)
fmt.Print(string(reply))
```

Comment: What is the protocol for a “reply”?

Answer (score 1):

```
io.CopyN(ioutil.Discard, conn, 5000)
```

it will read the first 5000 bytes and discard them. This is assuming each reply is exactly 5000 bytes though.

If the reply's are strings separated by new lines (such as http or irc), you could use buffio

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
reader.ReadString('\n')
secondline := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first reply is always the same size in bytes. Both replies are xml.